# R bat file - ERROR Error in load(name, envir = .GlobalEnv) : empty (zero-byte) input file Calls: sys.load.image -> load

Tags: r, batch-file

I have two virtual machines. Both installed with R Open 3.4.2 One machine works with out fail and this bat file works perfectly from the task scheduler.

REM on Microsoft Windows

```
"D:\Program Files\Microsoft\R Open\R-3.4.2\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD BATCH "C:\Users\abraboin\Documents\forecasting regression based\forecast_opera.txt"
```

I have another machine that suddenly stopped working. I have tried adding R to the path, reinstalling R and and R studio. Nothing works to get the task scheduler to run again with out getting this error.

> Error in load(name, envir = .GlobalEnv) : empty (zero-byte) input file
>
> Calls: sys.load.image -> load

When I click the `.bat` file to run the script manually just as the task scheduler would call this file...it works and runs the script no problem.

As anyone else run into this problem? I need to get this back up and working as soon as I can.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: No it just pulls up the command prompt with the active directory for where the bat file is

Comment: it seems like your run path is not working and it cannot find the file, OR the file is empty.

Comment: Which file do you think is empty? I have move the saved work space into the working directory and the directory where the bat file exists too. I have updated the Path for the R.exe

Comment: I experience the exact same issue. @user7044908 , did you come up with a solution by now?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, when firing the .bat file from doubleclick everything went well, but somehow when being fired from windows task scheduler this "empty (zero-byte)" error kept rising. Some sources in the internet suggest to delete `.RData` file, however I did not find such a file (not even a hidden one) neither in the R installation path nor in the project path.

After studing https://github.com/gastonstat/tutorial-R-noninteractive/blob/master/02-batch-mode.Rmd

it turned out, that adding `--no-restore` to the .bat file resolved my problem. My .bat file looks now like

```
@echo off
R CMD BATCH --no-restore D:\ScheduledTasks\yourRScript.R
```

You can also use `--vanilla` instead of `--no-restore`.